# Rewrite PayPal Token URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, paypal, token

i got the following htaccess rewrite rules set up:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?id=$1&sub=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /index.php?id=$1&sub=$2 [L]
```

Everything is fine, until it comes to processing payments true Paypal. Paypal returns the Success-URL like this:

```
http://example.com/checkout/success?token=EC-33Y7337627092313R&PayerID=QFQHDF7LULQR8
```

Witch causes the Payment to "fail" because of the ?-Questionmark in the URL - everything is fine when replaced with an &-Ampersand.

What is the best practices / rewrite condition to solve this issue?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rules are replacing the query string, so your `token` and `PayerID` parameters are completely lost.

Add [the [QSA] flag](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA) to your rules to preserve the query parameters.

Comment: Side note: You can reduce the number of rules you need in your `.htaccess`. `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]` will cover both trailing-slash and non-trailing-slash versions via the `/?`. Same thing can be done with the second set of rules.